# What is the most recent log file in logrotate utility

Tags: logrotate

I have multiple log files `abc-log`,`abc-log.1`, and `abc-log.2` rotated by `logrotate` utility. Among these rotated log files which is the log file which contains the recent logs?
Is it `abc-log` or `abc-log.1`?

Comment: Why not do a `ls -l` and find out by looking at the timestamp reported there?

Answer (score 2):

`abc-log` would contain the currently incoming log data; `abc-log.1` would be the newest file that is safe to remove or compress. (You can also look at the timestamp of the files to double-check.)

This is, of course, assuming you don't use software which logs to abc-log.1 directly, but that would be a near-malicious break of convention, I guess.

I should point out that rotating logs requires the program to be able to re-open its logfiles (so `logrotate` can rename the old one and the program will log to the new one), the docs on the `copytruncate` configuration option might be helpful here:

> **copytruncate**
>
> Truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old  log  file  and
>   optionally creating a new one.  It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and
>   thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever.  Note that  there  is  a  very
>                 small  time  slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost.  When
>                 this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place.